# How to install jad file on the Black Berry Simulator?

Tags: blackberry-simulator

I am going to work on the BB Simulator to test the application. I have one jad file 
(which is the beta version of my app). What are the necessary things do i need to follow to work it out?

Is there any doc to follow step by step?

Also please let me know that is there any screen shot tool (Except JL Cmder) to capture the screen on the BB Device.

Thanks
Chandra

Answer (score 0):

A JAD file is an information file that goes with the COD file that has the software. 
You should be able to get the COD file from the same place you got the JAD.
Open the BlackBerry browser,

enter the web link to the JAD file in there and

your application will be installed on your BlackBerry simulator.

Comment: Hi, I will try this...I got to know that need to install the Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy and some other things. Can you please drop some comment on this?

Comment: Hi I have mounted the build directory.. but if i click the jad file i am getting the below error Did you install Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files?>

Comment: Hi Yoko, i have given the steps in the following link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416593/how-to-resolve-this-application-requires-the-following-module-which-is-not-ins

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is going to the emulator, click on the File menu then click on "Load Java Program", select the .jad file and then search the app icon on the menu items.