# How to resolve "This application requires the following module, which is not installed: net_rim_bb_qm_platform"?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I am testing the BB Application (Beta version) on the simulator.

I have run the mds simulator. I have followed this step as well.

When i run the mds simulator i am getting this below:

```
<2012-02-23 20:53:58.598 IST>:[47]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = BBM, 0 platform ap
p controls have been loaded successfully>
<2012-02-23 20:53:58.598 IST>:[48]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = BBM, Schedule relo
ad plugin controls task with interval [86400s]>
<2012-02-23 20:53:59.020 IST>:[49]:<BBM_MDS>:<ERROR>:<LAYER = KeyNego, Cannot in
itialize AES-256: Did you install Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files?>

<2012-02-23 20:53:59.020 IST>:[50]:<BBM_MDS>:<ERROR>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Excep
tion, net.rim.application.ipproxyservice.b.a: Initialize failed>
<2012-02-23 20:53:59.020 IST>:[50]:<BBM_MDS>:<ERROR>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Excep
```

*Policy:*

1. Download jce_policy-6.zip file.
2. Extract the jce_policy-6.zip file.
3. In the JRE security folder of your system JRE (by default, this folder is located at C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_20\lib\security), replace the files, local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar, with the versions provided in the .zip file you downloaded.

After that i have started the BB SmartPhone simulator. I am getting the below error

This application requires the following module, which is not installed:
net_rim_bb_qm_platform

How to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

net_rim_bb_qm_platform indicates the absence of, or an older version of, BlackBerry Messenger.

Either install/update BBM on the simulator, or use a newer simulator with up-to-date BBM.